# Is there any advantages related to Performance in Oracle View

Tags: oracle

I'm learning about Oracle Views and I got the concept of views but little confused about performance.

I was watching video and there I listen that oracle view can increase the performance. Suppose I have created view like below.

```
CREATE VIEW SALES_MAN
AS
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE JOB='SALESMAN';
```

Ok now I have executed query to get SALES_MAN detail.

```
SELECT * FROM SALES_MAN
```

Ok now confusion start.
I listened in video that once the above query `SELECT * FROM SALES_MAN` will be executed the DATA/RECORD will be placed into cache memory after hitting the oracle DB. and if I will execute same query( IN Current Session/Login ) Oracle Engine will not hit to Database and will give you record from CACHED-MEMORY is it right?

But I have read on many websites that **View add nothing to SQL performance** [more](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_hints_views.htm)

Another Reference that says view not help in performance. [Here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1291563605946)

So Views increase performance too or not?

Comment: No, views do **not** increase performance. They are as fast or slow as the underlying SQL statement. Maybe that video of  yours was talking about _materialized_ views? They can indeed improve the performance for a specific statement.

Comment: No they didn't discuss anything related to `materialized` views. In short there is no Performance advantages in views until we realize or manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is just a kind of virtual table defined by a query. It has no proper data and performance will depend on the underlying table(s) and the query  definition.

But you also have **Materialized View** wich stores the results from the view query definition. Data is synchronized automatically, and you can add indexes to the view. In this case, you can achieve better performances. The cost to pay is

- more space (the view contains data dupplicated),
- no access to the up to date data from the underlying tables

Comment: yes, but note that if performance is important, these 2 points are no brainer, for instance in a reporting database

Comment: Yes I know, requirement is requirement. I think `Materialized View` can be good in Data Ware House. any how that is another story. Thanks I got the point.

Answer (score 0):

You (and perhaps the creator of the un-cited video) are confusing two different concepts.  The reason the data that was in the cache was used on the second execution was NOT because it was the second execution of the view.  As long as data remains in the cache, it is available for ANY query that needs it. The very fact that the first execution of the view had to get the data from disk should be a strong clue.  And what if your second use of the view wasn't until hours or days later when the data was no longer in the cache?  The answer remains.  A view does NOT improve performance.